# Generate CRC32 checksum of file swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy, crc32

I have a .zip file inside the project and I am transferring it to the external ESP32 via Bluetooth. But I need to send the CRC-32 checksum at the end of the sending file. I don't have any idea how to generate it.

Can anyone help me with how to do it in the right way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60199267/1974224?

Comment: Yes, I did but It seems like the CryptoSwift is a better way to do it.
Btw thanks for the link @Cristik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have found one amazing framework called CryptoSwift. This made my day. Here is how

- Get file `Data` from the file path.

I have a function which returns `Data` from file name and type.
And CryptoSwift has the extension of Data which converts the `crc32` by calling simply `.crc32()`

and than call crc32()

```
let crcChecksum = Utils.sharedInstance.getFileData(forResource: "firmware", withExtension: "bin").crc32()
```

For mote detail.

https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift

Comment: Thanks @Cristik I have added few things